# Django convert list of models into a queryset keeping the order?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm extending django rest with my own fancy ordering class, the return type of which is a list of models in a certain important order.

Is it possible to convert the list of models into a queryset while keeping the ordering?

I've tried the below but the ordering is lost:

```
ModelName.objects.filter(id__in=ids_ordered)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That's not possible. Do you really need a queryset? Can you do the ordering in the SQL itself? You can also try changing the order of applying methods, so that you first do everything you need to do using a queryset, and then convert to a list and do the ordering.

Comment: I dont, but `def remove_invalid_fields` which my results are passed on to does. (in this file https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/filters.py ) . It might be possible in SQL but Id rather not resort to that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are asking, but it is totally and completely possible to set the ordering on a queryset, using the `.order_by()` method. Check out the [API documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) for full details, but you can do something like:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2005).order_by('-pub_date', 'headline')
```

If you're building your own fancy ordering class on top of queryset, this should be available to you.